# extending sections in Laravel using routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have use the content of 'index' page in the 'home' page using routing.Now i need to use the same 'index' page content on 'leyland' page situated on CarBrands Directory(See image ) but i am unable to do so as i am using url '/car-brands/leyland' as it doesn't import the JS/CSS files that are linked on 'index' page. Its working perfectly if i use only '/leyland' in the url. I need to use the above url as it is clear to understand. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image: This is the project structure]

[image: This is the web.php file]

Comment: You need to account for relative pathing, e.g. if you're on `example.com/car-brands/leyland`, and your css is loaded via `<link href="stuff.css"`, then the browser is going to request `example.com/car-brands/leyland/stuff.css`.  you HAVE to use local absolute urls, e.g. `<link href="/css/stuff.css" ...>`

Comment: Thank u very much got it~!!

Answer (score 0):

You do everything right, but you suppose to create a extended layout as it says in documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates